# Typo in http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms?

Tags: bug

there is a typo in the last line of this page i think. 
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat-rooms

`At 100 reputation you also get access to the "Upload image" button in chat.`

It should be 1000 instead of 100, shouldn't it?

Comment: Both privileges are awarded at 100 reputation; the page is correct

Comment: Ok, thank you for clarification. I've read it once again and now I understand. Regards.